# In a keyed data.table, changing the value of the key variable at a certain `where` sets key to `NULL`

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to ask why the data.table in the example below loses its key when I change the value of a key variable at a certain `where` subset. And whether it's necessary.

```
library(data.table)
example(data.table)
setkey(DT,x)   # one key var only
DT[J("a"), x := "z"]
DT
   x y  v v2  m
1: z 1 13 84  5
2: z 3 13 84  5
3: z 6 13 84  5
4: c 1  7 NA  8
5: c 3  8 NA  8
6: c 6  9 NA  8
7: z 1 42 NA 42
8: z 3 42 NA 42
9: z 6 42 NA 42
```

so that works just fine. However, I've lost my key:

```
key(DT)
NULL
```

I guess that by reassigning the key column `x` above the key is erased. Maybe the key should be remembered, i.e. there should be an implicit `setkey(DT,x)` to keep `x` as the key? Thanks!

I'm using version 1.8.6. by the way.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need `J('a')`, `DT['a', x:='z']` will do the same.  But maybe this is a good feature add.  Like `levels` for factors there could be an `updatekey` function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `setkey`'s help file:

> ‘setkey()’ sorts a ‘data.table’ and marks it as sorted. [...] The
>     columns are sorted in ascending order always.

When you replace elements in any of the keyed columns, the `data.table` is no longer ordered (or at least can't be guaranteed to be), so the key is unset to reflect that changed reality.

An easy solution is to just immediately reset the key:

```
## Creates the example data.table
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
setkey(DT, 'x')

## Immediately resets the (possibly multicolumn) key
setkeyv(DT["a", x:="z"], key(DT))

key(DT)   
# [1] "x"
```

Comment: yeah, I do something like that - sounds like a reasonable solution to me. just wanted to see what you guys think. cheers!

Comment: hmm, I realize that might have been a stupid question - I haven't thought about the undone ordering at all. thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: +1 @FlorianOswald We have thought about maintaining the sort order but that would add overhead to check if the new values changed the order (like in your example). If it did it automatically someone will surely stick it in a loop of updates and wonder why it re-sorts on each iteration! So `:=` does the quickest and safest thing it can, but it's up to you when to reset the key. Quite unusual to need to update key values I guess, too. There could be a new argument `maintain.key`, though. Hm. That's not a bad idea ...

Comment: `maintain.key` filed as FR#2480. Nice to have but not a priority.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I completely agree with what you are saying. particularly the loop thing. So the current setup makes a lot of sense. In my application I have something that exogenously changes the value of the key at some point - some sort of "move of nature". I can see that being unusual, but for me the ability to do so (even with the current solution) is very valuable.

Comment: @FlorianOswald Good. Yes if data.table required you to maintain the key, that would be worse. This way you have options. `maintain.key` could do it faster than a whole `setkey` afterwards, though, so that would be nice.  You can of course go 'under-the-hood' and `setattr` the `sorted` attribute directly, instantly. That caries the risk of ending up with an invalid key (if you make a mistake). You could write a 5-10 line function that did what I'm describing `maintain.key` will do, yourself, if you need to.